# Is it possible for two different regions to have the same closure?

Tags: general-topology

I'm just wondering: Is it possible for two different "regions" (nonempty connected open sets) $R_1,R_2$ to have the same closure?

If you take a disk in the plane, for example, like $|z-a|<r$, the closure is $|z-a|\leq r$, and I don't think any other region has that closure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about the punctured disk $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid 0 < |z - a| < r\}$?

Comment: That's slick, Michael!

Comment: More generally, you could remove finitely many points from the disk and get a region with the same closure.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious example is: if $A = \{x\in \mathbb{R} \mid \lvert x - a\rvert < r\}$ then the closure is indeed $B = \bar{A} = \{x\in \mathbb{R} \mid \lvert x - a\rvert \leq r\}$. So $A$ and $B$ are different, but $\bar{A} = \bar{B} = B$. This is of course because $B$ is closed.

If you are looking for two different open sets with the same closure, then consider any interval $(a, b)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and remove a finite number of points. Then the closure of that set is $[a,b]$ no matter which points (or how many) you remove. In fact you can remove any set of rational numbers from $(a,b)$, the closure is still $[a,b]$.

This example can, of course, be generalized to any (open) set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas! For the first example I think your set $B$ is not open. (I would like regions to be open.) The second one is good.